# Why are there so many restrictions on /ŋ/ in English?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonemes, phonotactics

In (GA, SSBE) English, the phoneme /ŋ/ (in *ri**ng***) seems to have so many restrictions:

- **it rarely occurs after /u:/, if at all:** the only word that I have been able to find in which /ŋ/ occurs after /u:/ is *mung/moong*
- **rarely occurs after /ʊ/:** as in *loong, boong* and occurs instead of /ʌ/ in dialects where /ʌ/ is realized as [ʊ] (mainly Northern British)
- **/ŋ/ never occurs in the start of a syllable in English**
- **rarely (or never?) occurs after /aɪ/**
- **rarely (or never?) occurs after /aʊ/**
- **rarely occurs after /eɪ/**
- **rarely (or never?) occurs after /ɔɪ/**
- **almost never occurs after /əʊ/**

Another phoneme that has many restrictions is /ʒ/ but I assume it can be attributed to the fact that [**/ʒ/** is not a native phoneme](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/563773/387044) and I am not interested in that phoneme. (There is also /h/ with many restrictions, but I am not interested in that either.)

Is there any reason why /ŋ/ has so many restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the unusual behavior of [ŋ] can be explained in its historical origin from simplification of the consonant cluster [ŋg] (in words where [ŋ] occurs in modern English outside of the clusters [ŋg] and [ŋk]).

Compare the behavior of the consonant cluster [mp]: like [ŋ], [mp] cannot occur at the start of a syllable and rarely occurs after a diphthong or "tense" vowel.

The clusters [nd] and [nt] can be found after diphthongs more frequently than [mp] or [ŋ], but that is part of a general pattern where syllables ending in coronal consonants such as [d], [t], [s], [z] are allowed to have more complicated structure than syllables ending in non-coronal consonants.